# Change a value of a hidden field in the markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markup

Is there a way to change a value of a hidden field in the markup (with jquery or js) so I could use that new value once I'm out of the script (i.e. in a different script that would be triggered later)?

Lets say :

```
<form>
...
  <input type="hidden" name="prev_address" id="prev_address" value="no">
  <input type="hidden" name="prev_job" id="prev_job" value="non">
...
</form>

<script>
...
$('#prev_address').toggle( nbr_daysD < min_depuis_days ); 
document.form.prev_address.value = 'yes';

$('#prev_job').toggle( nbr_daysE < min_emploi_days ); 
// OR
$('#prev_job').value = 'yes';
...
</script>
```

The values are changing (if I use an alert) but not the markup...

Thanks

Comment: How are you checking the markup? Firebug? You're not viewing the source are you?!

Comment: Why do you need to change the markup when the value is still changed?

Comment: @Josh because view source doesn't show the current state of the markup, it shows the original markup loaded from the server.

Comment: @Josh Well, I have a second script that is looking for "$('#prev_job').val()" and the new value didn't show up (so there must be an error on that script). No I wasn't looking in the view-source ;) But thanks

Comment: "No I wasn't looking in the view-source ;) But thanks" - Had to ask, just in case :P

Comment: @morespace Than perhaps you can elaborate on this remark: "The values are changing (if I use an alert) but not the markup..."

Answer (score 5):

jQuery uses [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get/set the value of an input (or select or textarea) element.

You want `$('#prev_job').val('new value');`

If you want to see the changed value, you can use Firebug to view the current DOM. The built-in "view source" feature of most browsers simply displays the original HTML as sent by the browser; no scripts are run against it so you will not see your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify a value after the page has been loaded, you can access that modified value with other scripts, but if you do a view-source on the page, you will see the original values.